Missing money from wallet
I bought $20 worth of Solana 2 days ago and I still have not received it. I paid with Stripe, the solana address was correct, double checked and money has been deducted from my bank account. What do I do? The wallet I use is the Phantom Wallet

Please allow up with your Bank if you used a credit card / debit card
If you are able to locate a Transaction number please provide that here.
You can also check on chain also using the Solana Explorer here
https://explorer.solana.com

Depends on where you bought them from but if you used Phantom then your bank may have declined a "crypto" transaction. Best to check with them ... most banks automatically reverse a failed / cancelled transaction within a few days.
